# alexa - capture values not defined in custom type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My alexa application has a buy intent with a custom data type which has some values, say

> vehicles : [car, bus]

If user says

> I want to buy a bike

alexa defaults to the fallback intent with no information about what user said .

How can I capture the 'bike' value so that I can respond with

> we dont support '*bikes*' at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to capture it already assuming your intent is set up correctly in the Skill's Interface.

I don't know exactly how your skill is set up or what language you are using for development, so I can't tell you the code to access it, but the JSON request will look something like this:

```
"request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "intent": {
    "name": "BuyIntent",
    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
    "slots": {
      "vehicleType": {
        "name": "vehicleType",
        "value": "bike",
        "resolutions": {
          "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
            {
              "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.[skill-id].vehicleType",
              "status": {
                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH"
              },
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you can figure out how to access the 'value' property under the your slot for vehicle types, you will have the value the user said! You just need to capture it in a variable and interpolate it into the string you send back to Alexa to speak from.

The reason this works even without a defined slot type is because Alexa actually stores two different types of value for a slot. One is the value I mentioned before, this stores what the user actually said. The second is found in the 'resolutions' section of the slot, and holds the value in the slot type that Alexa matched with the user's speech. When no match is found, Alexa still returns the slot with the value for what the user said, and sets the status code of the resolutions to "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH", which means no corresponding slot type was found.

As far as why your skill is getting a fallback request instead of one for your Intent, I can't tell you with the information you gave, but the lack of a defined vehicle type for 'bike' isn't the reason. Do you have an utterance set up for the buy intent that matches the phrase you're using to interact with the skill? Something like: "I want to buy a {vehicleType}"

Answer (score 1):

Custom slot types will work with values that aren't explicitly defined. So you should be able to say `I want to buy a bike` even if `bike` isn't in the `vehicles` slot type.

As far as I know, the only alternatives are the `AMAZON.LITERAL` and `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot types.